# Will restoring a backup unroot my rooted device again?

Tags: root-access, backup, factory-reset, restore

I have made a full backup of my formerly unrooted android device using Android Debug Bridge, later rooted it and now would like to restore the backup while maintaining root access.

Will this work by restoring the backup with `adb restore` or will my phone possibly be unrooted (just like with a factory reset)?

**Edit:** My *Samsung Galaxy Nexus GT-i9250* is currently running on Android 4.3, the backup was made with the same version using the command `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f`.

**Update:** I restored the update and my device is still rooted (checked with *Root Checker* from *Super User*), though a few apps and some data were not restored.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't restore the system partition (I don't know whether this is backed up by ADB), your root access should be preserved.

You could just make a backup of the state of your device *now* and restore it, when needed.

Comment: `adb backup` backs up files, not partitions :) Still, the idea of another backup I support – just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used systemless root(Android 6.0+), I'm not sure if that will remove your root access. If you used system root(Android 5.1 and below), this will not remove root.

Regarding,

> adb backup -all

If this is the command you ran, this backs up only the /data partition, not any other partitions. For a full backup of /system /boot /recovery /data, etc. you would have to perform a nandroid backup from recovery.

Comment: Thank you!
I ran the command `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f` and have Android 4.3. This means a restore would be safe?

Comment: If you had ran the backup with the `-nosystem` modifier, I would say yes, there is a high chance of you being safe. Since you didn't specify, `adb backup` automatically backs up the system. This would unroot your device. You could install root after restoring from the backup though as root does not require your data to be wiped.

Comment: @MitchB why would that unroot the device? I don't think it would remove files, just restore what was backed up. Still, restoring a system backup across different Android versions is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Izzy I have tried to find some documentation of the adb command but it is sparse. I am going off of what I found on this [wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Android/adb) and I believe that if it were to restore the `/system` partition then that would remove root if the root is `/system` based, which is likely given that @xoxox is running 4.3. Also, I don't think they said whether their backup and live versions are different.

Comment: ADB backups are file based, not partition based. So to my knowledge, a restore would just write back the files from the backup, overwriting existing files, but not deleting anything. I never tried restoring a full backup, though, so I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @Izzy Hmm, you bring up a good point. I also have not ever restored a backup. Perhaps if we knew the root package they used, we would be able to determine which root it is (though that may be out of the scope of this question). I'm hesitant to say that their root status will be unaffected though. Worst case scenario, re-root is required and I do not know of any root packages that require a full factory reset.

Comment: I'd go with GiantTree here: If it really would backup everything (which it does not), and on restore does a wipe and unpack, another backup done right before that should be fine to restore root. Really sure we can only be if we try it, e.g. with a "redundant device": Wipe it, root it, do `adb backup`, install some additional app, then restore the backup and see.